# Local time String to DateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, tryparse

I am reading .csv file where string values have native (авг=aug) name of months (datestring): "01-авг-17 00:00:00", but instead of "авг" there is correct local month name in my native language. Using the following code I am trying to convert it to datetime format, but it doesn't work:

```
Public Shared Function GetDateTime(ByVal datestring As String) As Date

        Dim format As String = {"dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss"}
        Dim result As Date
        If Date.TryParseExact(datestring, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Nothing, result) Then
            Return result.ToString
        Else
            MsgBox(datestring & " is not in the correct format")
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

For some reasons the program goes to "else" statement. If I use English equivalent "aug" it works fine. How can I solve this problem? I was trying to use something like "CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU") but it didn't work.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

### Update

I want to be able to use different csv files, which can include name of month in different language (eng or ru). So I understood that I can use the following statement (for Russian):

```
Date.TryParseExact(datestring, formats, New CultureInfo("ru-RU"), DateTimeStyles.None, result)
```

So for English I need to use something like `New CultureInfo("en-US")`. However, why doesn't `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`  work? I can use several if condition to apply different culture settings. Do you know "smart" solution for that? How can I easily convert name of month in English or Russian language?

Comment: from the screen shot the problem might be the .csv encoding

Comment: I changed from Ansi to Unicode, it appears without question marks, thanks, but still the problem didn't go.

Comment: removing curly brackets in 'format' string definition helps?

Comment: nope, actually I used massive of strings, but to make it simplier I remove all unnecessary string formats.

Comment: @badscrool did you try with Russian culture after changing the econding?

Comment: Thank you for notification, yeah, it works, great! Thank you very much!

Comment: My understanding of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is that it is a basic "English"-like parser - it's not "All Cultures".

Comment: The statement `DateTime.ParseExact("01-авг-17 00:00:00", "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU"))` works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your function is of `Date` type but you are returning a *string* (`Return result.ToString`). So I'm assuming you want a `string` to be returned. If that is so, this should work for you:

```
Public Shared Function GetDateTime(datestring As String) As String
  Dim ru As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU")
  Dim format As String = "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss"
  Dim result As System.DateTime = Nothing
    If DateTime.TryParse(datestring, result) Then
        Return result.ToString(format, ru)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I attached screenshot